# How to fail a front squat?

Tags: squats

From all sources I see on the internet, people front squat outside a squat rack and then throwing it. I have two questions:

1. Is it not possible to fail a front squat safely in a squat rack?
2. What exactly is the procedure for safely failing a front squat? And how does it differ based on if one is squat rack or not?

Comment: Will you be in a squat rack or not?

Comment: 1. You don't see videos of people failing in a squat rack with safety pins because you just need to fall over or let go so it's uninteresting.